# Is there any way to create a prepared statement based on user selection?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I know that the very definition of a prepared statement is that it's prepared, but is there any way to create a statement based on user selection?

For example, if there were a list of 10 groceries that the user could then select as they wished, and they selected 4 items. Is there a way to dynamically create a prepared statement based on that?

I've googled but haven't found anything that suits my needs.

```
$stmt = $bd->prepare("UPDATE member SET fname = ?, lname = ?, college = ?, address = ?, contact = ?, password = ? WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $fname, $lname, $college, $address, $contact, $password, $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username);
$stmt->fetch();
```

So this is what my prepared statements look like, and they work just fine, but I can't see a way to be able to put an unknown number of variables in. I am also in PHP 5.3, so mysqli_result etc are all out of the question.

Comment: yes there is ... please try *something* first

Comment: You can do it. *Try it*, show it and we will help you to get it working :)

Comment: added some code, but I honestly can't see how I'd even attempt it.

Comment: @user3822332 See the dupe link, that should give you a start/an idea/solution

Comment: starting to sound like more of an issue with table structure - so whats the table you want to add to look like ?

Comment: Thanks guys, looking at other solutions now, but having trouble understanding them. Essentially, I want to run a select query based on someones selections, but it could be any number of selections from just 1 up as far as 10.